# value of temp.size () changes when I step out of it

Tags: c++, string, debugging, size

Hi I am doing this code

```
  #include <iostream>
  #include <string>

  using namespace std;

  int function0(void){return 50;}

  int main (void)
  {
        string temp("Hi how are you");

        for(int i = 0; i <temp.size();i++) //Line 1
        {
              cout<<"A"<<endl; //Line 2
              function0(); //Line 3
        }

  return 0;
  }
```

I tried to debug this code, at first when I stepped into **Line 1** `str.size() = garbage`, when I stepped into **Line 2** `str.size() = 14`, and when I stepped into **Line 3**, `str.size() = garbage`

I understand `size()` is a function for string class where it returns a `size_t` variable, it's value shouldn't change when I step out of it, same with `function0()`, so why does it change, when I debug the program.

PN: I am using Code::Block 17.12, GDB debugger.

Comment: Do you build with optimizations enabled? Are you "stepping" using the GUI only, or using GDB commands? And what do you mean when you say "stepping ***into***"? Normally stepping *into* something means entering a function as opposed to stepping over. If you step *into* `function0` then of course the debugger will not know what `temp` is since it's no longer in scope.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand "build with optimization enabled"?, I am stepping in using the GUI only, by stepping into I mean move to the next line of code

Comment: How to debug. Someone, please post a link,  i lost=)

Comment: yes I understand, if your program goes to another function, you can't access variables that are on a different scope

Comment: It's not clear to me *what* you perceive as failure exactly, but the value return by `temp.size()` is a temporary. It's supposed to be correct for the duration of the comparison alone. After that, however that value came to be, it's gone.

Comment: I thought if it was a function similar to function0(), where it returns a variable of size_t, and it's value should remains equal to 14 for the duration of the scope, just like function0(), but if it is supposed to be correct for the duration of the comparison alone, then it makes sense when it gives me garbage value when the program goes to the next line

Comment: the value that the string stores itself of course persits as long as the string is alive, but what you get from calling `size()` is a copy of that value that has a different lifetime than the string itself